# Typescript `custom type` only works in type world, but not actually working with `function`

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples, type-inference, tail

I have a custom type called [Tail](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab?fbclid=IwAR2T8R9Mt3SHy7LfZkt-oeHJoN2AYX-SAvMzbjp_zeGVTFyGQiwB7ts_iYU), it will return array type without first element:

```js
type Tail<T extends any[]> =
    ((...t: T) => any) extends ((_: any, ...tail: infer TT) => any)
    ? TT
    : []

type test11 = Tail<[1, 2, string, number]> // [2, string, number]
```

The code above is working fine, but when using with function, it's not working now:

```js
function tail<T extends any[]>(arr: T): Tail<T> {
  return arr.slice(1) as Tail<T>;
}

let result = tail(['', 1]); // res: (string | number)[]
```

[image]

The `result` should be only `number`, but instead, it shows `(string | number)[]`, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Typescript specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.6). Specifically, it says:

> The rules [given] mean that an array literal is always of an array type, unless it is contextually typed by a tuple-like type.

In your call to `tail`, the only hint to the type of `['', 1]` is `any[]`. (See Section 4.15.2. I've skimmed it and it seems to say this, but someone can call me out if I'm wrong.) Therefore, its type becomes `(string | number)[]`, and you call `tail` with the signature

```
tail<(string | number)[]>(arr: (string | number)[]): (string | number)[]
```

You can reproduce the problem as

```
let i = ['5', 5]
let x: [number] = tail(i)
```

And you'll see it vanishes in

```
let i: [string, number] = ['5', 5]
let x = tail(i) // x: [number] (inferred)
```

I believe you simply cannot have the tuple type inferred in this situation. However, it should be fine, since you shouldn't be passing literals into `tail` that often.